# How to find out if a page is running in Phantom JS (or Poltergeist)?

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, poltergeist

How to test within Javascript whether it is running Phantom JS (via Poltergeist) or on a regular browser?

Use case: Suppress logging during testing.

Using Poltergeist, Capybara, Ruby.

Comment: Did you try checking `navigator.userAgent`? http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/browser-detail?browser=PhantomJS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reliably detecting PhantomJS-based spam bots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862728/reliably-detecting-phantomjs-based-spam-bots)

Comment: @ArtjomB. - How do I turn off the logging of phantomjs in ruby ? It spews info into the console.

Comment: @ArtjomB. - I made a new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117205/ruby-how-do-i-turn-off-the-logging-for-phantomjs